# PySpark Dropping columns after join

Tags: pyspark

I have the following code:

```
a = df.alias('a')
b = dfDates.alias('b')
cond = [a.adjTransactionDate == b.TransactionDate, a.GroupByFld == b.GroupByFld]
c= b.join(a, cond, 'left')

c=c.drop('adjTransactionDate','a.GroupByFld')
```

I'm finding the last line removes the 'adjTransaction date field from the dataset, but the GroupBYFld remains.

If I simply do:

```
c=c.drop('adjTransactionDate','GroupByFld')
```

Then both GroupByFld's are removed from the dataset.

How do I remove just the GroupByFld belonging to source A?

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to figure out the issue but ended up doing this instead:

```
a = df.alias('a')
b = dfDates.alias('b')
cond = [a.adjTransactionDate == b.TransactionDate, a.GroupByFld == b.GroupByFld]
c= b.join(a, cond, 'left').select(b.TransactionDate, b.GroupByFld,a.Amount)
c.show()
```